# Using Apache Flink's Elastic Search sink vs Kafka sink with Elastic Search connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have several Flink data streams that will ultimately end up in Elasticsearch.  Is it better to use Flink's Elasticsearch sink or Flink's Kafka sink combined with Kafka's Elasticsearch sink?  What would the tradeoffs be?

Comment: If you are already using Flink, why not continue to use it? What issues are you having with it?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question.  I am asking whether it would be better to use Kafka as a sink as opposed to the Elasticsearch sink directly.  That is, should I have all of my Elasticsearch updates/inserts inside a Kafka topic and configure Kafka's ES connector, or configure Flink's ES connector.  What would the performance profile be and what would configurations be like?  For instance, how would batching work when using multiple streams that end up in ES vs batching from Kafka's ES connector?  I.e., would a per-topic configuration be better than a per-stream configuration?

Comment: Ah, sorry, thought you meant _Kafka Connect_ Elasticsearch sink vs Flink. At a high level, performance depends on your own hardware, and Kafka allows for backpressure/retires and more parallel consumption. Otherwise, it's possible writing directly to Elasticsearch could result in errors/dropped events